mb_detect_encoding seems to detect UTF8 but decoded string still shows weird characters
I'm struggling to detect the right encoding to insert an UTF8 CSV dataset to a database.
In my DB, all the text fields are created using utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci (this is how my Wordpress is configured so I can't really change that). So I assume it's a kind of UTF8 encoding..
For all the fields I'm using this function. Without this function, all inserts had strange characters. Now all the fields look good.
$row_data[$key] = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');

... except for two fields. These two fields are collected in the same CSV but from another source (another web site) so I think for some fields in the CSV, the encoding may be different.
Here is an example with a sample data that doesn't want to be inserted into the DB.
<?php

$text = "GergÅ‘ RÃ¡cz";

// Détection de l'encodage
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($text);

echo "encoding detected: " . $encoding;
$utf8_text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'ISO-8859-1','UTF-8');

echo "\ntext to UTF-8 : " . $utf8_text;

# php ./p.php
encoding detected: UTF-8
text to UTF-8 : Gerg▒? Rácz

It's like it's already UTF-8 but not really. And I can't identify which encoding it is. Garbage characters in, garbage out.
Any idea ?
Many thanks !!

You're converting the UTF-8 text to ISO-8859-1 text.

mb_detect_encoding() doesn't detect anything, it guesses. Do not rely on it. Text encoding is metadata that should be known at all times.

Store your source code in UTF-8 encoding, too. Treat codepages like Latin-1 aka ISO8859-1 as legacy encodings and avoid them in modern software.

@Sammitch Thanks for your reply. If I have to know at any time what my encoding is, how can I actually know when the dataset comes from a source I dont manage ? Like, is this string ""GergÅ‘ RÃ¡cz";" UTF-8 or something else ? I got the right result (Gergő Rácz) only by using mb_convert_encoding($value, 'Windows-1252' ,'UTF-8').

The source should be telling you either via metadata or documentation.

ő (U+0151,  Latin Small Letter O With Double Acute) isn't present in ISO-8859-1. Use Windows-1252 instead as follows:
<?php

$text = "GergÅ‘ RÃ¡cz";

// Détection de l'encodage
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($text);

echo "\nencoding detected: " . $encoding;
$utf8_text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'Windows-1252','UTF-8');

echo "\ntext to UTF-8 : " . $utf8_text;

?>

Output: php .\SO\78678820.php
encoding detected: UTF-8
text to UTF-8 : Gergő Rácz


Many thanks ! Does that means I need to change the way my tables are defined in Mysql to store these fields with the right encoding ?

No, they wouldn't. You face a mojibake case, and better to prevent it rather than to push for fixing it subsequently…

there's something I don't get. If "GergÅ‘ RÃ¡cz" is already UTF-8, why can't I get the right value (Gergő Rácz) with utf8_decode ?
